# Empty tag doesn't work in some browsers warning in PhpStorm (Laravel 7)

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, laravel-7

When I want to use Laravel 7 component, the PhpStorm shows an annoying warning. How could I fix such behavior or disable this warning?

[image: example warning]

Comment: Can you share more details? What is this "annoying warning"? Where's the code to trigger that behaviour?

Comment: @NicoHaase e.g. `<img src="https://myUrl.com" alt="thumbnail"/>` shows this warning or also `<hr/>`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try disabling **HTML | Empty tag** inspection in **Settings | Editor | Inspections**

[image: screenshot of settings]

Comment: I can't find this in the latest version. Does anybody else have this problem?

Comment: still there in 2021.3, **Settings | Editor | Inspections, HTML | Empty tag**

Comment: Just found it there :)